# generic methods is used to eliminate overloaded methods

Tags: java

I read a little about generic methods , and I found that it is used to eliminate overloaded methods.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer arr[] = { 12, 55, 66, 54 };

    printArray(arr);
}

public static <T> void printArray(T arr[]) {
    for (T a : arr) {
        System.out.print(a.toString() + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

before knowing anything about generic methods I used to do something like the following :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Integer arr[] = { 12, 55, 66, 54 };

    printArray(arr);
}

public static void printArray(Object arr[]) {
    for (Object a : arr) {
        System.out.print(a.toString() + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

what is the differences between the two ways ...?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For the specific use case you've mentioned, there is no difference, since all objects have a `toString()` method.  If you wanted to return a `T` or `T[]`, or you needed `T` to implement some generic interface, or the like, then you would need a generic method.  (That said, generics tend to be used more with collections than arrays.)